# Ruby script with mysql2 gem - compare db date to Date.new

Tags: mysql, ruby, ubuntu

I am writing a Ruby script which uses the mysql2 gem and runs under apache2/passenger.It does not use rails.

The script iterates through a mySql query result and compares a database date to today to get the elapsed time in days. The problem is that the resultant string from subtracting a database date from Date.new is a string like -2457521/1. The correct answer should be 0.

I have tried converting the date to a Ruby date with Date.parse() and Date.strptime() but get the same result. How can I subtract these dates to get the number of days between them?

Here is a redacted code extract from my script.

```
require 'mysql2'

class Uptime

  def call(env)

    results = con.query("SELECT * FROM Uptimes ORDER BY Up DESC LIMIT 10")

    flag = 0

    results.each(symbolize_keys: true) do |row| 

       if flag == 0 
          last_event = row[:Up]  # => 2016-05-12
          flag = 1
       end

    end  

#        last_event = Date.parse("#{last_event}")

#        last_event = Date.strptime("#{last_event}" "%Y-%m-%d") 

         days = Date.new - last_event # => -2457521/1


        [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, [html]]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the fact that you are using Date.new when I run `Date.new` in irb it returns the following:

`#<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`

That looks like a 1st January of some year.

If you use `Date.today` instead that will return the current date to you.

I get this when I run that in irb `#<Date: 2016-05-12 ((2457521j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` notice 2016-05-12 vs -4712-01-01 this is also the reason why your result is negative.

Hope this answer helps :)

Comment: That's close but Date.today - last_event returns 0/1

Comment: Please can you tell me what is the result of running `last_event.class`?
I notice you have commented out `Date.parse("#{last_event}")` maybe last_event is not of the Date class when you are subtracting it from `Date.today`

Comment: I have previously checked class and found them to be both Date. Anyway, (Date.today - last_event).to_i gives me the right result so I will mark your answer correct, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :) and thank you for accepting my answer